# Spacing under square root

Tags: spacing

How can I remove space automatically added above expression under square root when I write for example`\sqrt{k^2_t-k^2}`. In fraction`\frac{\sqrt{k^2_t-k^2}}{1}` there isn't this type of space.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It depends on where you are writing the first square root. if you type `$\sqrt{k^2_t-k^2}$` you'll get the root with no additional space, since expressions between `$...$` (or `\(...\)`) are in-line mode. Otherwise if you type `\[\sqrt{k^2_t-k^2}\]` you'll get the root with space, because it is `displaystyle` mode.

Comment: You can remove it by using `\textstyle` prior to `\sqrt`, note however that this affacts more than just that space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When TeX is in display-math mode, the numerator and denominator of a fraction are rendered in text style. If you want to apply text style to other material in a display-math environment, you need to provide the directive `\textstyle` explicitly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\[ % start an unnumbered display math group
\sqrt{k^2_t-k^2} \qquad
{\textstyle\sqrt{k^2_t-k^2}} \qquad
\frac{\sqrt{k^2_t-k^2}}{1}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address a follow-up comment by @mavzolej, who claims that inserting the `\textstyle` instruction doesn't "work" if the expression inside the square root term contains `\langle` (and `\rangle` too, presumably). Unfortunately, he/she didn't provide compilable code to demonstrate the correctness of the claim. For sure, changing `\sqrt{k^2_t-k^2}` to `\sqrt{\langle k^2_t-k^2\rangle}` does *not* imply that imposing `\textstyle` won't succeed in reducing the overall size of the square root term:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\stuff{\sqrt{\langle k^2_t-k^2\rangle}}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\stuff \quad\mbox{vs.}\quad \textstyle\stuff$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work if I have \langle under the root. What can I do in this case to remove the white space?

Comment: @mavzolej - Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. For sure, the solution works just fine for, say, `\sqrt{\langle k^2_t-k^2\rangle}`.

Comment: [That's](https://i.imgur.com/16U8wt3.png) what I have after adding `\langle` and `\rangle`, a lot more white space than without them, and `\textstyle` does not help.

Comment: That was my output for `$\sqrt{\langle k^2_t-k^2\rangle}$`.

Comment: @mavzolej - Please see the addendum I just posted to my answer, in which I contrast the sizes of `\sqrt{\langle k^2_t-k^2\rangle}` when typeset with `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, it's not working in my case, but that's probably because of some packages I added to my document.